# How to connect multiple db tables to users_profiles in laravel

Tags: laravel, database, database-design, schema

i am starting a new a site in laravel and i would like to use an sql file from the old corydating script since i can't design my own.
what i have done is upload the sql file to my db and used [Laravel Migration Generator](https://github.com/bennett-treptow/laravel-migration-generator) to generate the schema files,
but the problem is i don't understand how to impletment this.
E.g the gender table:

```
Table structure for table `tbld_gender`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbld_gender` (
  `GenderID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `L1Gender` varchar(6) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `L2Gender` varchar(12) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `L3Gender` varchar(12) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `L4Gender` varchar(12) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TopSorted` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`GenderID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbld_gender`
--

INSERT INTO `tbld_gender` VALUES(1, 'Male', 'Male', '', '', NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE GenderID=1;
INSERT INTO `tbld_gender` VALUES(2, 'Female', 'Female', '', '', NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE GenderID=2;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

The code above is from the sql file.

```
Schema::create('tbld_gender', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->smallIncrements('GenderID')->unsigned()->primary();
            $table->string('L1Gender', 6);
            $table->string('L2Gender', 12);
            $table->string('L3Gender', 12);
            $table->string('L4Gender', 12);
            $table->tinyInteger('TopSorted')->nullable();
```

And th above code is from the generated schema file.

Now the problem is how do i insert data into the gender db table? and in the scripts the gender have only 2 fields male and female for the user to chose from.

The users table displays the gender of the user through the gender id
like so

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbld_users` (
  `UserID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `MembershipID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `RemainVIPContacts` bigint(20) unsigned default '0',
  `SiteID` tinyint(3) unsigned default '1',
  `Name` varchar(75) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `ProfileName` varchar(75) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `Email` varchar(75) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(75) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `GenderID` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  `HeightID` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  ...
```

The above code is from the sql file.

```
Schema::create('tbld_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('UserID');
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('MembershipID')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('RemainVIPContacts')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('SiteID')->default(1);
            $table->string('Name', 75)->nullable();
            $table->string('ProfileName', 75)->nullable();
            $table->string('Email', 75)->index('tblDUserIndexOnEmail');
            $table->string('Password', 75);
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('GenderID')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('HeightID')->nullable();
```

The above code is from the generated schema file.
Please i need help this understand this and implement this on my own
eg what is L4Gender is it for male field or female field?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `what is L4Gender is it for male field or female field?` not trying to be rude, but why are you asking us? This is _your_ table definition. Take a step back and think about your table design before converting your existing tables into new ones. For example, why does your gender table have 4 gender columns? Is this a requirement for your project?

Comment: Once you have a clear understanding of your table designs you will need to create a foreign key (FK) from gender to user. With that, you can create model relationships in Laravel. With model relationships, you can query, insert, update, ... your data. But it all starts with proper table designs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, actualy the the sql file is not mine, it's a file from the corydating php script that i want to adapt and use it in laravel.